# Spring Hystrix not triggered on inner methods

Tags: java, spring, hystrix

I'm trying to include Hystrix circuit breaker in a spring boot application.
My Application is a standard spring boot 1.4.1 with spring-cloud-hystrix v 1.2.0 app with a single controller class which calls a service class with an "aggregate" method.
This method internally calls two services using inner private methods.

If I annotate the "aggregate" method with @HystrixCommand everithing works fine, but if a annotate the other inner methods Hystrix seems to is not be triggered

This is my service class:

```
@Service
public class AggregationService {

    @Autowired
    Service1 service1Client;

    @Autowired
    Service2 service2Client;

    private static final String QUERY = "query";
    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    //@HystrixCommand(
    //    fallbackMethod = "emptyResult",
    //    groupKey = "aggregation-service",
    //    commandKey = "aggregate")
    public AggregationResponse aggregate(final AggregationParams params)
            throws ApiException, IOException {

        final String query = queryExplain(params);
        final WrapperQueryBuilder wrappedQuery = QueryBuilders.wrapperQuery(query);
        final SearchResponse aggregationResult = searchAggregation(params, wrappedQuery);

        return toDtoResponse(aggregationResult.getAggregations().get(params.getAggregationField().name().toLowerCase()));
    }

    @HystrixCommand(
        fallbackMethod = "emptyAggregationResult",
        groupKey = "aggregation-service",
        commandKey = "searchAggregation")
    private SearchResponse searchAggregation(final AggregationParams params, final WrapperQueryBuilder query) {

        return ... do something with service 2 ....
    }

    //    @HystrixCommand(
    //        fallbackMethod = "rethrowTimeoutException",
    //        groupKey = "aggregation-service",
    //        commandKey = "query-for-aggregation",
    //        ignoreExceptions = TimeoutException.class)
    private String queryExplain(final AggregationParams params) throws ApiException, IOException {
        final String queryAsString = ... do something with service 1 ....
    }

    private String rethrowTimeoutException(final AggregationParams params, final Throwable e) {
        log.error("On Hystrix fallback because of ", e);
        return null;
    }

    private SearchResponse emptyAggregationResult(final AggregationParams params, final WrapperQueryBuilder query, final Throwable e) {
        log.error("On Hystrix fallback because of ", e);
        return null;
    }

}
```

My controller method is :

```
 @GetMapping("{field}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public AggregationResponse aggregate(... some params ...) throws ApiException, IOException {

... omissis ....

        return aggregationService.aggregate(params);
```

My configuration class has these annotations :

```
@Configuration
@EnableHystrix
```

My application.properties contains:

```
hystrix.command.searchAggregation.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=1
hystrix.command.searchAggregation.circuitBreaker.errorThresholdPercentage=10
hystrix.command.queryExplain.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=1
hystrix.command.queryExplain.circuitBreaker.errorThresholdPercentage=10
hystrix.command.default.execution.timeout.enabled=true
```

I've intentionally kept the timeout for the execution isolation to 1MS in order to catch the hystrix execution.

The strange thing is that only the @HystrixCommand placed on the "aggergate" method seems to be triggered while the others not so if i comment the annotation on top "aggregate" no timeout error is triggered, if i uncomment the annotion a "missing fallback exeption" is triggered

I'm asking what i've missconfigured? Must @HystrixCommand be placed only on "called" method and can not be used onto internals ones?

Hope that my problem is clear (because to me is pretty obscure :) )

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javanica uses the [HystrixCommandAspect](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/blob/master/hystrix-contrib/hystrix-javanica/src/main/java/com/netflix/hystrix/contrib/javanica/aop/aspectj/HystrixCommandAspect.java) aspect to detect methods annotated with the `HystrixCommand` annotation, and it seems that the  [pointcut](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/blob/master/hystrix-contrib/hystrix-javanica/src/main/java/com/netflix/hystrix/contrib/javanica/aop/aspectj/HystrixCommandAspect.java#L72) defined affects only public methods.

UPDATE: there is a [bug report](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/issues/1020) related to this specific issue.

Comment: Thanks for the issue !! i wasn't able to find it. I've also tried to change method visibility to public but behaviour is the same, if method is not called directly hystrix is not triggered. This same environment is mentioned into the liked issue but no solution is provided (as i understood), i'm wondering if is possible to instrument methods without HystrixCommand annotation on google i didn't found any guide or example.
Right now i've split my class into three pieces and instrumented hystrix and everything works fine, but still i think this approach for my app is a little bit over engineered

Comment: The HystrixCommand annotation is just an high level simplification introduced by Javanica. If you need more flexibility you can implement your command in the standard way, i.e. by subclassing the HystrixCommand class https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Getting-Started#hello-world

Comment: @IlTera, What do you mean by "not called directly"?  When would a method not be called directly?

Comment: @jrahhali I think you need to look at here to understand. Directly means that I didn't called myService.hystrixWrappedMethod() but I called myService.someMethodThatCallesTheHystrixWrappedMethod(). In this case it seems that it won't work. Discussion: https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/issues/1020#issuecomment-165885957